# Can I install LiipImagineBundle with Symfony 5?

Tags: composer-php, liipimaginebundle, symfony5

I'm trying to install LiipImagineBundle with Symfony 5 but I'm getting this error :

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for liip/imagine-bundle ^2.2 -> satisfiable by liip/imagine-bundle[2.2.0].
    - liip/imagine-bundle 2.2.0 requires symfony/asset ^3.4|^4.2 -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this : [Add support for Symfony 5](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle/issues/1241)

Then it's a matter of time.